# How to disenable the blank at the end of a page in Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I need to insert a lot of "*" in the blank space at the end of my page.
The lines are auto height.

I need it to look like this:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

There is a band in the report called the "background" band.
You can maximize it's height to fit an entire page (right click it > "Maximize band height"). Then, you fill this band with lots of "*" in it's entire extension.

Now, you must make sure that the other elements in the other bands (your data) are not transparent, but opaque, so the "*" won't appear in the background of your data, but only in the rest of the page where things would be blank.